# How to return strings which occur more than 4 times in an excel doc

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, countif

Fairly new to excel, I have a document with rows and columns filled with names. Basically i want to be able to find if any names are there more than 4 times, and if so which names these are. What is the formula I would need to do this? I've tried iterations of countif and index but I just cant seem to get it right. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So, if you have your input values in column `A:A`. Enter this formula into `B1` and drag it down:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1,COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>=4),$A1,"")
```

And then you get your final result without blank cells in `C1` (and down) with this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B1000,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$1:$B1000)-ROW($B$1)+1)/($B$1:$B1000<>""),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")
```